# Dual switch for fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have two smart kasa switches that I used for a non wireless ceiling fan and it worked great. I replaced the fan with a wireless fan but now I can't make it work properly so that each switch controls the light and fan individually like before.

I attached a photo of my my kasa switches wiring. One switch makes the red wire hot and the second switch makes the black wire hot.

My electrical wire coming from the ceiling is the ground, white, black and red wire. The ceiling fan has a white, black, green and blue wire.

[image: Kasa switch]

Comment: How did you wire the ceiling fan receiver, and are you wedded to the Kasa switches?

Comment: The ceiling fan receiver is pre installed on the wireless hunter fan with remote. I'm no expert but I'm going o try and check the line load wires on the kasa switches to see if they are not mixed up.

Comment: What model of fan is it?

Comment: Hunter Hardwick ceiling fan. I think the issue is with the way the fan works and not the wiring. I ended up leaving the fan switch on and then I can use the light switch to turn on the light on and off. I will use the remote to activate the fan and the light if I want.